# mongoose find with $regex not return expected result if value stored with special character

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to build a search function that searches on username or full name ... it works fine but if username like this "example.name" or "example_name" it did not return in result if I searched like this "examplename" or "example name" how to solve this problem to return a matched characters even that special characters

**User Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt-node");
const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");
const schemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
firstName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
lastName: { type: String, trim: true },
fullName: {type: String, trim: true},
username: { type: String, trim: true, unique: true, lowercase: true },
email: {
  type: String,
  unique: true,
  trim: true,
  lowercase: true,
  required: true
},
password: { type: String, select: false },
gender: { type: String, default: "male" },
birthDate: Number,
location: { type: [Number], index: '2d' }, // [<longitude>, <latitude>]
bio: {type: String, default: ""},
profilePhoto: {type: String, default: "default-user-profile.jpg"},
private: { type: Boolean, default: false },
favouriteUsers: [{ type: schemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: "users" }],
blockedUsers: [{ type: schemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: "users" }],
tempPassword: String,
tempToken: String,
socialId: String,
favouriteRequests: [{ type: schemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: "users" }],
requests: [{ type: schemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: "users" }],
followers: [{ type: schemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: "users" }],
following: [{ type: schemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: "users" }],
playerId: {type: [String], default: []}
},
 { timestamps: true }
);
userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: "This {VALUE} is used" });
userSchema.index({ "$**": "text" });
userSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified("password")) return next();
  if (user.password) {
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function(err, hashedPassword) {
  if (err) {
    return;
  }
  user.password = hashedPassword;
  next();
  });
 }
});

userSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
 const user = this;
 if (!user.isModified("firstName") && !user.isModified("lastName")) return 
  next();
 if (user.firstName || user.lastName) {
  user.fullName = user.firstName + " " + user.lastName;
  next();
 }
});
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password) {
return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
```

**Code**

```
function search(keyword){
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
const User = require('../models/users');
let str = keyword.replace(/[`~!#$%^&*()|+\=?;:'",<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, ""); 
let key = new RegExp(str, "ig");
User.find({
  $or: [
      { fullName: { $regex: key } },
      { username: { $regex: key } },
      { firstName: { $regex: key } },
      { lastName: { $regex: key } },
      { email: { $regex: key } }
    ]
   }).exec(async (err, users) => {
     if(err) return reject(err);
     resolve(users);
   })
  })
 }
```

**Example 1**

if keyword entered "ahmed ibrahim" or "ahmed.ibrahim" result is okay as expected

**result for example 1**

```
[
{
    "_id": "5b40d19ae4fc082ca8f2ff3b",
    "profilePhoto": "http://localhost/public/male-image.jpg",
    "firstName": "Ahmed",
    "lastName": "Ibrahim",
    "username": "ahmed.ibrahim65356",
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "fullName": "Ahmed Ibrahim"
}
]
```

**Exmaple 2 the problem**

if the keyword is "ahmedibrahim"

I expected the previous result put returns nothing an empty array [] hot to solve this or any suggestion match characters even contain special characters

Answer (score 0):

It won't work basically because you are searching for "ahmedibrahim" and it cannot relate with any of the fields in your document.

So for this specific scenario, what I would do is create a new field say "concatFullName" which should save as firstname+lastname, then use that field contactFullName in your find ie.

contactFullName : { $regex: key }

Try below sample for aggregate,

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate({
    $project: {
        docs: "$$ROOT",
        concatname: {
            $concat: [
                '$firstName',
                '$lastName',
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        concatname: {
            $regex: "^ahmedIbrahim$",
            $options: "i"
        },
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        docs: {
            $push: "$docs"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: actually, I did this with the first and last name in one field fullName but my problem is with username contains any character so if it like that I have to remove all special characters of the username and put it in another field without special character like the 
username: "example_name",
searchField: "examplename"

Comment: So I guess you have to do either aggregate or mapreduce.

Comment: what is the solution or the main concept of it by aggregation

Comment: Here is a sample,

Comment: @IbrahimKeshta Added sample in the first comment.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your sample it works fine if entered "ahmedibrahim" but its possible to replace special characters in username rather than concat first and last name?

Comment: During project, try filtering the username field using regex instead of concat.